# zsh apt list options completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm used to using tab completion in bash to get `apt list --upgradable` by typing `apt l`<kbd>tab</kbd>`--u`<kbd>tab</kbd>, but I can't do the same thing with zsh: `--u` doesn't expand to `--upgradable` when I press <kbd>tab</kbd>.

I googled up some solutions suggesting installing zsh-completions and adding `setopt completealiases` to `./zshrc`, but neither of these helped.

Is there any way to make it work like it did in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old question but since this has bugged me as well I took a look. I couldn't make heads of tails out of the zsh completion stuff for apt and trying to use the bash completion in zsh via bashcompinit failed also.

However, I'm happy to report that this has been fixed as of version 5.8 of zsh which was released in early 2020. That version of zsh is bundled with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and will be in the soon to be released Debian 11.

The commit is actually here: [zsh commit 44614: apt list option completion](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/commit/2b41606fe7b57c33ca05e13e2ab7a3409456889e)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it once I get to my Ubuntu machine and mark it as the answer then.

Comment: Works like a charm with zsh 5.8 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps here to get other features as well:
https://github.com/abhigenie92/zsh_to_fish

1. Install oh-my-zsh

`sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"`

2. Clone necessary plugins.

`git clone git://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/zsh-autosuggestions
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-history-substring-search
git clone https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting.git ${ZSH_CUSTOM:-~/.oh-my-zsh/custom}/plugins/zsh-syntax-highlighting`

3. Add plugins to `~/.zshrc` as

`plugins = ( [plugins...] zsh-autosuggestions zsh-history-substring-search zsh-syntax-highlighting)` Note: make sure zsh-syntax-highlighting is the last one in the above list.

4. Fix background theme issues (Not necessary depends on your theme.)
   Add the following line to your `~/.zshrc`.

`ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_HIGHLIGHT_STYLE='fg=white'`

5. Restart zsh

`source ~/.zshrc`

If you like the answer, please consider starring the github repo.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it only solves the problem half-way: I get completion for `apt list`, but not for `--upgradable`. It does show the suggestion when I start type `--u`, but pressing `tab` doesn't autocomplete it.

Comment: is there an update for this issue?